# What is the technique using in this option tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, jquery-select2

I found a [site](https://ikman.lk/en/ads) (please click "Select Location" option select for action) with pop up selection. I can't find out what is the jquery plugin used There. Or what is the code behind it. Thanks

Comment: No plugin was used, it is HTML that is generated on the server side and returned via an ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually just loading [this page](https://ikman.lk/en/ads-locations) into a modal. Theres no Jquery used on that page.
This is a pretty odd way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

The page https://ikman.lk/en/ads-locations opened in the popup seems to use this plugin : http://ui.saltside.io/demo/forms/select-list.html

You can see "Saltside Technologies" copyright at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. The code is  in JADE but I just need HTML/js/css code, I tried to search in Google to convert them into HTML, didn't works. What should I do?  Thanks